# Multipad sample sources download

Tags: winapi

It is mentioned in here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/using-the-multiple-document-interface. I have tried to search the Internet, but with no luck so far. Where do I download the sources for Multipad sample application from?

Answer (score 1):

The interesting bits are in the documentation, but as a compilable sample, the MULTIPAD sample was available with Microsoft Visual C++ 1.5x (like 30 years ago).

As of today, you can find it here from [Microsoft Visual C++ - Version 1.52c (Microsoft) (1995)](https://archive.org/details/Microsoft_Visual_C_-_Version_1.52c_Microsoft_1995) (disclaimer: I'm not sure about the legal terms, I have the original CD Rom) and get into the `MSVC15\SAMPLES\MULTIPAD` directory that contains the following files:

```
16/09/1994  15:00             766  MP300.ICO
16/09/1994  15:00          12 531  MPFILE.C
16/09/1994  15:00           7 856  MPFIND.C
16/09/1994  15:00           4 477  MPINIT.C
16/09/1994  15:00          10 901  MPPRINT.C
16/09/1994  15:00          26 414  MULTIPAD.C
16/09/1994  15:00             558  MULTIPAD.DEF
16/09/1994  15:00           3 518  MULTIPAD.H
16/09/1994  15:00           2 681  MULTIPAD.MAK
16/09/1994  15:00           7 366  MULTIPAD.RC
16/09/1994  15:00             766  NOTE300.ICO
16/09/1994  15:00           2 977  RESOURCE.H
```

Comment: thank you very much!! What's on the disk will definitely do for me)